# Magento Issue: price reverts to Default Value from Website Value

Tags: php, magento

I am running 2 websites in magento EE 10.1.1.

Website A contains products in USD Pricing

Website B contains the same products in INR Pricing. (I need different prices in INR, so price conversion didn't help)

Issue is whenever I update the pricing of product1 in Website B in INR, It reflects in the default value.

For a day, product1's pricing in Website A and in Website B shows correct value. But later on product1's pricing in Website A(USD) takes up the default value, which is in INR. Now my site shows INR price values in USD currency.

Example:

```
Product1 price in Website A= USD 100

Product1 price in Website B= INR 5000

Product1 price in Default = USD 5000 (Default config currency is set to USD)
```

1 Day later....

```
Product1 price in Website A = USD 5000
```

Please Helpp :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't have different prices for stores but only for websites (unless you use one of the custom extensions which extends this functionality). This also has to be enabled System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price.

Then you can't show different currencies in admin, only at the frontend.

So what you shall do is to create 2 websites, set different currencies for both and in admin enter both prices in base currency using conversion rate (e.g. £99.99 for WbsiteA and £84.64 for WebsiteB. At the frontend £84.64 will be converted into €99.99). or you can set different currency for both website.

second option you can use Advanced Pricing extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-pricing-3001.html or http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing.html